# How to capture a multi-line regex between two tags based on a match condition?

Tags: regex, multilinestring

I have a text composed of text fragments delimited by "[1]" tags. I would like to use regular expressions to select (and eventually delete) those delimited fragments that do not contain asterisks.

example

```
[1] "Q 1  Gender * modal2"
Gender          1   0.0165 0.00144 0.6990  0.555   
modal2          2   0.1588 0.01387 3.3636  0.010 **                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
[1] "Q 1  Gender * interv"
Gender          1   0.0165 0.00144 0.6876  0.495
interv          4   0.0563 0.00492 0.5868  0.765             
[1] "Q 1  Acad_categ * Acad_field"....
```

In the text presented, the second fragment between the second and third tags [1] would be the one chosen.

Comment: I'm not seeing why the second one would be chosen. They all contain asteisks. Anyway I've added an answer that should do what you seem to be asking. Happy to update it if it needs work.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. But in any case the proposed solution does not work.  I had tried with [1](\n|.)*?[1] but it only identifies all text between the [1] tags, i.e. all text.

Comment: And what is it you want exactly?

Comment: the corrected example is this: 

[1] "Q 1 Gender * modal2" Gender 1 0.0165 0.00144 0.6990 0.555 modal2 2 0.1588 0.01387 3.3636 0.010 ** Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 [1] "Q 1 Gender * interv" Gender 1 0.0165 0.00144 0.6876 0.495 interv 4 0.0563 0.00492 0.5868 0.765
[1] "Q 1 Acad_categ Acad_field"....

the section to be identified should be the 2nd

Comment: The second contains an asterisk. Not clear on what you want here. And what the match should be.

Comment: Try my answer again? There was a mistake which I’ve now corrected. To use non-greedy matching for the main part of the match.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does it match and what should it match? All of your examples so far contain asterisks so it's not clear what you want here. Maybe update the example to be accurate and the explanation of what you want to match so that it also clear and accurate?

Comment: It works perfectly for me based on how I understand what you want. See https://regexr.com/7cvpn

Comment: Eaxample:
[1] "Q 1 Gender * modal2" Gender 1 0.0165 0.00144 0.6990 0.555 modal2 2 0.1588 0.01387 3.3636 0.010 ** Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 [1] "Q 1 Gender interv" Gender 1 0.0165 0.00144 0.6876 0.495 interv 4 0.0563 0.00492 0.5868 0.765 [1] "

the fragment to be selected is [1] "Q 1 Gender interv" Gender 1 0.0165 0.00144 0.6876 0.495 interv 4 0.0563 0.00492 0.5868 0.765 [1]

Comment: Here it is, matching exactly with the regex from my answer: https://regexr.com/7cvq0

Comment: I have re-checked the code in my text and now it works fine. thanks a lot!!

Comment: When asked for clarification please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. A big problem is that the code in your question is not formatted correctly. Each line of code needs to be indented at least four spaces for it to be formatted properly. You can also select your code and then press `{}` above the box in which you have written the code. Also, whenever you give an example please show the desired result.

Comment: Could someone please click on "Edit" and vote to approve Nigel Peck's edit? @Nigel, I expect by now you wished you just did the edit without asking for approval. :-)

Comment: Not an option unfortunately @CarySwoveland or I definitely would have done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this…

```
/\[1\][^*]+?(?:(?=\[1\])|$)/
```

**Plain English Explanation**

Match `[1]` followed by one or more characters that are not an asterisk and can include newlines, followed by (but not including in the match) either `[1]` or the end of the text being matched.

**Technical Explanation**

```
\[1\]
```

Matches `[1]`.

```
[^*]+?
```

Matches one or more characters that are anything other than an asterisk, in a non-greedy way (so the shortest match it can that still finds the next part at the end of it).

```
(?:(?=\[1\])|$))/
```

Without capturing anything - `(?: ... )` - match either…

```
(?=\[1\])
```

The following characters are `[1]` but it doesn’t consume it on the match, just checks that it’s there (positive lookahead assertion).

Or…

```
$
```

The end of the string that is being matched against.

Comment: You may want to change `[^*]+?` to `[^*]*?` in the event that the string contains `[1][1]`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/OLmXzn/1) is a regex101.com demo should you wish to link it, possibly after modification. Why "something like this" as opposed to "this".

Comment: I considered that but then if it was empty there wouldn’t be any fragment to match, right? Seems like a call for the OP. I’m happy with my choice of `+` for this answer.

Comment: “Something like this” because there are other ways that it could be achieved, different choices that could be made, like your suggestion of `*` rather than `+`. So, “something like this” as in it’s intended as a starting point rather than a final solution.